# navigation title overlaps bar button item after rotating back to portrait

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios10

Im trying to truncate the tail of a label when the text is too long. Everything works initially (screenshots attached). Problem arises when rotate to landscape. Navigation bar extends to cover left and right navigation bar items. Same problem when rotate back to portrait. I placed border around label and nav bar to help illustrate (red for nav bar, blue for label). Is there a way to prevent nav bar from overlapping left and right bar items?

```
        UILabel *broadcastLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        broadcastLabel.text = BILocalizedString(@"Broadcast with long titleeeeeeeeeeee");
        [broadcastLabel sizeToFit];
        broadcastLabel.textColor = BIColorForPaletteKey(BIColorPrimaryText);
        broadcastLabel.font = BIFontForStyle(BIFontFixedNavigationStyle);
        broadcastLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

        CGSize navBarSize = self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer.frame.size;
        UIView *titleView = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, navBarSize.width, navBarSize.height)];
        [titleView addSubview:broadcastLabel];
        self.navigationController.navigationItem.titleView = titleView;

        titleView.layer.borderWidth = 1;
        titleView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
        broadcastLabel.layer.borderWidth = 1;
        broadcastLabel.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;

        [titleView addConstraint: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:broadcastLabel
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                  toItem:titleView
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                              multiplier:1.f
                                                                constant:4.f]];

        [titleView addConstraint: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:broadcastLabel
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                  toItem:titleView
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                              multiplier:1.f
                                                                constant:0.f]];

        [titleView addConstraint: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:broadcastLabel
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationLessThanOrEqual
                                                                  toItem:titleView
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                              multiplier:1.f
                                                                constant:0.f]];
        if (navBarSize.height >= tallSize)
        {
            /* Two lines*/
            UILabel *onewayLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
            onewayLabel.text = BILocalizedString(@"one-way message");
            [onewayLabel sizeToFit];
            onewayLabel.textColor = BIColorForPaletteKey(BIColorPrimaryText);
            onewayLabel.font = BIFontForStyle(BIFontFixedSmallStyle);
            onewayLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

            [titleView addSubview:onewayLabel];

            [titleView addConstraint: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:onewayLabel
                                                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                                   relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                      toItem:titleView
                                                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                                  multiplier:1.f
                                                                    constant:0.f]];

            [titleView addConstraint: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:onewayLabel
                                                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                                   relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                      toItem:titleView
                                                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                                  multiplier:1.f
                                                                    constant:-4.f]];

            [titleView addConstraint: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:onewayLabel
                                                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                                   relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationLessThanOrEqual
                                                                      toItem:titleView
                                                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                                  multiplier:1.f
                                                                    constant:0.f]];
        }
```

[all three screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/582eL.jpg)